# Not able to insert elements dynamically into Semantic-UI Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, accordion, semantic-ui

I am trying to insert **dynamic content** inside a **Semantic-UI Accordion**. Basically I have to render a JSON input to the html as an Accordion.

Here is the script and the html I am using for the above purpose:-

```js
<script language='javascript'>

  $(document).ready(function(){
  
     $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
     
     $('.ui.accordion').accordion({onOpen: function() { // function for dynamically inserting content inside clicked element in accordion
      var id = $(this).attr('id'); //gets the id of the clicked element in accordion
      var obj = find_key_value(json_data, id); // a function for finding the key in the json and its corresponding value
      for (var prop in obj){ //appends new content inside the clicked element in the accordion
        $(`#${id}`).append(`
        <div class="title">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          ${prop}
        <div class="content"></div>
        `);
        $('.ui.accordion').accordion('refresh');   
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="ui styled accordion">
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    A
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="A"></div>
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    B
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="B"></div>
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    C
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="C"></div>
</div>
```

Also in the above script I am using the **onOpen** callback for accordion which is used to perform some action after an element is opened as mentioned in the [Semantic-UI Docs](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html#/settings)

Suppose json_data is as follows:-

```
json_data = {
'A' : {
     'A1':{'A12':[]},
     'A2': [],
     'A3': [],
     }, 
'B' :  {
     'B1':[],
     'B2': [],
     'B3': {'B31':[]},
     }, 
'C' : {
     'C1':[]
      }
}
```

and if **A** is clicked then **A1**, **A2**, **A3** should be dynamically inserted into `A's` content and similarly for `B` and `C` as well as for nested objects like `A1`, etc. So all the elements in the json should be inserted dynamically into the accordion only when the object key corresponding to it is clicked or opened.

There isn't much documentation for this on Semantic-UI and the code which I shared above does not work. Any idea how to do this?

[**EDIT:** This JSON has been created from a python dictionary so it might not look like a regular JSON]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating htmls whenever accordian is open you can create whole structure when page gets loads . So , firstly loop through outer array i.e : `A , B , C` then check if the data inside suppose `A` is `object {}` or `array []` depending on this you need to change your logic and append whole html inside your dom.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json_data = {
    'A': [{
      'A1': {
        'A12': ["A12a"],
        'A13': ["A13a"]
      },
      'A2': ["az"],
      'A3': ["a3"],
    }],
    'B': [{
      'B1': ["b1"],
      'B2': ["b2"],
      'B3': {
        'B31': ["b31"]
      },
    }],
    'C': [{
      'C1': ["c1"]
    }]
  }
  var html = "";
  $.each(json_data, function(key, value) {
    //creating title for outer array
    html += `<div class="title">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i> ${key}
      </div> <div class="content" id="${key}"><div class="accordion">`
    //child inside A,B,C( A1,A2..etc)
    $.each(value[0], function(k, v) {
      html += `<div class="title">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
         ${k}
      </div>`
      //check if the value of object is {} or []
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Object]') {
        html += `<div class="content"><div class="accordion">`
        //i.e : A1 { A12 , A13}
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(v).length; i++) {
          html += `<div class="title">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
         ${Object.keys(v)[i]}</div>`
          //loop through i.e : A12 :[""]
          $.each(v[Object.keys(v)[i]], function(ky, vl) {
            html += `<div class="content">${vl}</div>`
          })
        }
        html += `</div></div>`
      } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Array]') {
        //simply get content []
        html += `<div class="content">`
        $.each(v, function(ky, vl) {
          html += `${vl}`
        })
        html += `</div>`
      }
    })
    html += `</div></div>`

  })

  $("#outer").html(html) //add to outer div
  $('.ui.accordion').accordion(); //intialzie


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha512-8bHTC73gkZ7rZ7vpqUQThUDhqcNFyYi2xgDgPDHc+GXVGHXq+xPjynxIopALmOPqzo9JZj0k6OqqewdGO3EsrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js" integrity="sha512-dqw6X88iGgZlTsONxZK9ePmJEFrmHwpuMrsUChjAw1mRUhUITE5QU9pkcSox+ynfLhL15Sv2al5A0LVyDCmtUw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="ui styled accordion" id="outer">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with loading everything at once (which I have already tried) is that the actual json_data will be very big and nested. So the entire HTML takes hours to load. Thats why I am looking for dynamic loading or lazy loading, i.e., load the content (or create HTML for them) only when required (when element is clicked)

Comment: I would suggest you to use above way because in your current code you are creating whole html part again and again on every click so that's just unnecessary . Also , it will be more complicate to find which json then append there ..etc etc and your json structure is very complicated as well.

Comment: The reason this JSON looks weird is that it has been created from a python dictionary (because I am using a python framework called Django). So actually this JSON is meant to act like a dictionary and not like an actual JSON so that the content of the Accordion can be dynamically inserted only when required. As I mentioned in the question itself, I just want to insert the values in JSON for that particular key and not go inside each of the nested/sub values of that key recursively/iteratively.

Comment: You have change json structure again which one are you using in your actual code ?

Comment: My bad. I entered the wrong json before. The newer one replicates the actual json which I will be using. And I will not be creating the html part again and again. I will be just appending the html for the new content only when they are required. Also I will be using a recursive function to find the key and its corresponding value which I'll be adding in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.forEach((v,i,a)=>{ //appends new content inside the clicked element in the accordion
    $(`${id}`).append(`
        <div class="title">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          ${a[i]}
        <div class="content"></div>
        `);
        $('.ui.accordion').accordion('refresh');   
})
```